# How does XAdES-X-L compare to RFC4998 Evidence Record Syntax

Tags: digital-signature

[This SE question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/21293/396) describes a scenario I don't fully understand the use case or how 4998 can help correct the issue.

How and when should XAdES-X-L be used, and where should RFC4998 be used?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between Evidence Records and XAdES signatures is that, well, the first consist in evidence records (ensures data integrity) and the second in signatures (ensures data integrity AND authenticity).

The various XAdES formats enable persons and legal entities to **sign** data. In an increasing number of countries, this has the same **legal** value as signing a **paper document**, however with stronger security (forging a digital signature is theoretically impossible if you use proven, secure digest and encryption algorithms).

There are however some issues that can arise with such signatures: algorithms become weaker and revocation information for signing certificates may become unavailable (once a certificate has expired, the CA is not required to keep its related revocation information). As a result, archiving digital signatures for long periods may become impractical... unless you keep, along with the signature, all its related revocation information while also ensuring that it cannot be forged should the algorithms (that were used at its creation time) become weaker/broken.

And that's exactly what the XAdES archive/long-term formats bring: they add revocation information to the signature and then issue a new timestamp (with a stronger algorithm this time) over this updated signature. This new timestamp hence covers the original signature value, along with the added revocation information.
By issuing such archive timestamps each time an algorithm becomes weaker and/or when a signing certificate expires, you can virtually archive the original signature forever.

Evidence Records, on the other hand, are "just" evidences to which a timestamp (cfr. RFC3161) has been applied. This can be used to prove that some piece of data actually existed at a given point in time, but it misses the **legal** purpose of a signature (i.e. someone marked his/her agreement to something specified in a given document).

So, to sum it up: XAdES-A must be used when you need to store the archiving stuff **within** the signature. Otherwise, ERs can do the same job...